# EF saving property instead of base property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So i have this property in my partial class overriding the property of my POCO

```
    public new double PaidOvertime
    {
        get
        {
            if (!InHoures)
            {
                return Math.Round(base.PaidOvertime/ 7, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.PaidOvertime;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (!InHoures)
            {
                base.PaidOvertime = value * 7;
            }
            else
            {
                base.PaidOvertime = Math.Round(value, 2);
            }
            statsChanged();
        }
    }
```

The thing is, when it come to saving, EF save the value of this property. I would like EF to save the value of the base property or the private variable behind the base property.

Is ther a workaround or something that im missing?

*PS : when i say 'saving' i mean saving to the DB*

Comment: @Serge we are using ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator With WCF Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you are using some inheritance mapping otherwise it should not work at all.

Once you use `new` in derived class you are telling .NET that this is the implementation you want to use every time it works with your class instance. The base implementation is used only if you cast class to base type and work with it as with base type - the question is if this works with EF.

Simply don't do that. `new` keyword in method and property declaration is something you should use only if you have control over all code using your object. Otherwise you never know which implementation will be called. EF is not your code.